# IIS 7 URL Rewrite doesn't work if the url has a question mark in it

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm using the URL rewrite feature of IIS7

I'm trying redirect a URL like this

```
example.com/?parameter=abc
```

to a URL like this

```
example.com/somedirectory
```

the URL redirect works well if the source URL doesn't contain a question mark in it.

pls help

-Vivek

Answer (score 5):

IIS7 redirects don't by default match query strings in the pattern so you have to add a condition as well as the pattern with `{QUERY_STRING}` matches the pattern `parameter=abc`