# IIS URL Rewrite/Redirect Remove trailing Question mark from Request URL, if no query string Parameter exists in URL

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

**How To Remove Trailing Question Mark from URL if there is no Query String**

I am trying to rewrite a rule where it removes trailing Question mark from requested URL if there is no Query string.

**For Example**:

1. If Requested Url is http://www.web.com/hh/?. which does no have a query string it has to be
   reit has to be
   rewritten as http://www.web.com/hh/.
2. If Requested Url is [http://www.web.com/hh/?k=1](http://www.web.com/hh/k=1). which have a query string it has to be
   rewritten as [http://www.web.com/hh/?k=1](http://www.web.com/hh/k=1).

**So Far I have tried not working**

```
   <rule name="Remove Question MArk" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*[^\?])\?$" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" appendQueryString="false"redirectType="Permanent" />
   </rule>
```

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL You probably need to learn why question marks are there first. Then you will know that you cannot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS 7 URL Rewrite doesn't work if the url has a question mark in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162946/iis-7-url-rewrite-doesnt-work-if-the-url-has-a-question-mark-in-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason that it cannot be because the rule actually removes it but the browser does not remove the trailing Question mark!